# change table into dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Some one please guide me on how to change my table as dataTable.

My table will be loaded dynamically using below code.

```js
$.post('geterpitem',{grn : $('#grn').val()}, function(responseJson) {
    if(responseJson.length!=null){
        var $tbl = $("#itemtable");
        $tbody = $tbl.find('tbody');
        $tbl.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var i = 1;
        $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
            rowNew.children().eq(0).append(i);
            rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemcode']); 
            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemname']); 
            rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['receivedqty']);
            rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text"  id="inspdate"/>');
            rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text"  id="accqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>');
            rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text"  id="rejqty" class="reject"/>');
            rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text"  id="rema"/>');
            rowNew.appendTo($tbody);
            i++;
        });
    }
}
```

Since I am new to this, Please someone help me to do.

Comment: try this link, https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html.

One observation from your code, writing html in JavaScript is not a good way, instead of that, use some html templates like mustache.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**HTML**

```
<table id="searchResultTable"  class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultscontainer">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
searchResultTable = $("#searchResultTable").dataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [20],
    "order": [[1, "desc"]],
    "ordering": false,
    "bFilter": false
});

searchResultTable.on('click', 'tr', DataTableRowClickEventHandler);

searchResultTable.fnClearTable();
for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){

    ....get values for Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4....

    searchResultTable.fnAddData([Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]);
}
```

Try below mentioned link for more documentation and examples,

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html